# Unable to run Calabash tests on iOS device for Xamarin app

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, calabash, calabash-ios

We are unable to get Calabash tests to run on a Xamarin app deployed to a real iPhone. We have tried downloading the sample app from:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/

It works when deploying to a simulator, but not when trying for a real device. We can install and run on the device, just not get it to work with Calabash.

The command we tried to run it with is:

```
APP_BUNDLE_PATH=~/Path/to/CreditCardValidation-Calabash/CreditCardValidation.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/CreditCardValidationiOS-1.0.ipa DEBUG=1 BUNDLE_ID=com.xamarin.calabash.example.creditcardvalidation DEVICE_TARGET=uuid-of-device DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://ip.of.phone:37265 RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1 cucumber
```

Output of the above is:

```
Using the iOS profile...

Feature: Navigation feature


  @ios_only

  Scenario: A user can navigate between each journey stage # features/navigation.feature:4


INFO: Using uia strategy: 'preferences'

Preparation took 0.087536 seconds

{

                        :app => "<snip>",

                       :args => [],

    :bundle_dir_or_bundle_id => "<snip>",

                  :bundle_id => "<snip>",

                     :device => "<snip>",

              :device_target => "<device-uuid>",

              :launch_method => :instruments,

             :launch_retries => 5,

                   :log_file => "/var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/run_loop.out",

                  :no_launch => false,

                    :no_stop => false,

                      :reset => true,

                :results_dir => "/var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00",

          :results_dir_trace => "/var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/trace",

                     :script => "/var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/_run_loop.js",

                :sdk_version => nil,

                       :udid => "<device-uuid>",

               :uia_strategy => :preferences,

                      :xcode => "6.0.1",

                 :xcode_path => "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

}


### Starting on <device-uuid> App: <snip> ###

2014-11-07 11:21:38 +0000 xcrun instruments -w "<device-uuid>" -D "/var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/trace" -t "Automation" "<snip>" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00 -e UIASCRIPT /var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/_run_loop.js &> /var/folders/w1/55hzwq792vqdrv8bgw69yvy40000gp/T/run_loop20141107-1711-1whcn00/run_loop.out

Failed to launch.

execution expired: execution expired

Running `curl http://ip.of.phone:37265/version` returns the expected json.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the following:

1. Connect the device via USB.
2. Make sure the bundle identifier matches the bundle identifier of the app.
3. Does the device appear in the out put of `xcrun instruments -s devices`?  If not check Xcode's Device window (Command + Shift + 2).  Make sure the device is listed and appears with no warnings.  If it appears with errors, quit Xcode, restart the device, relaunch Xcode. Rinse and repeat until the errors are cleared.  Sometime I have to connect my device to another machine to clear warnings.
4. Is the app installed on the device?  Calabash cannot install apps on physical devices.  See [this project](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app) for a demonstration of how to use ideviceinstaller to install an app on device as part of Calabash testing.  I've added a TODO to improve the README.md for that project.

> APP_BUNDLE_PATH=~/Path/to/CreditCardValidation-Calabash/CreditCardValidation.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/CreditCardValidationiOS-1.0.ipa

The [APP (preferred) and APP_BUNDLE_PATH](http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html#label-APP+and+APP_BUNDLE_PATH) environment variables are only used when targeting simulators.  They are ignored when targeting physical devices.